# Issue in importing ethnicolr package

Tags: python

I am trying to use the `ethnicolr` package to classify some names into their ethnicity and I seem to be running into a problem everytime I import `ethnicolr` on spyder in anaconda.

The error I'm getting is:
`AttributeError: module 'numpy.core' has no attribute 'numerictypes'`

Is there any way to fix this?

Code is:

```py
from ethnicolr import census_ln, pred_census_ln
```

Error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-5c35fcefc816>", line 1, in <module>
    from ethnicolr import census_ln, pred_census_ln

  File "/Users/palaash/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ethnicolr/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .pred_census_ln import pred_census_ln

  File "/Users/palaash/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ethnicolr/pred_census_ln.py", line 8, in <module>
    from keras.models import load_model

  File "/Users/palaash/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation

  File "/Users/palaash/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util

  File "/Users/palaash/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import data

  File "/Users/palaash/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data import experimental

  File "/Users/palaash/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/__init__.py", line 96, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental import service

  File "/Users/palaash/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/service/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.data_service_ops import distribute

  File "/Users/palaash/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/ops/data_service_ops.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops import compression_ops

  File "/Users/palaash/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/ops/compression_ops.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.util import structure

  File "/Users/palaash/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/util/structure.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import tensor_array_ops

  File "/Users/palaash/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops

  File "/Users/palaash/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1498, in <module>
    _NON_AUTOPACKABLE_TYPES = set(np.core.numerictypes.ScalarType)

AttributeError: module 'numpy.core' has no attribute 'numerictypes'
```

Comment: is your numpy fully updated ? (running on the latest version) its a common issue with such errors

Comment: Yes. I updated numpy too, but the same error keeps popping back